# Is there a way to jump to a specific section of a procedure in MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I want to jump to specific section of my main procedure from another procedure.  Basically I have an intro part of my main proc, and the rest of it I want to loop through, but from another procedure.  Is this possible?

```
main PROC
    call    otherProc
    section:
        ;Do something else
main ENDP


other PROC
    jmp    main.section ; Jump to section inside main...is this possible?
other ENDP
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, labels don't care where they are. Why haven't you tried it?

Comment: @Jester I tried using a section label inside main, but it said `undefined symbol "section"`.  I wasn't sure if I was using the proper syntax or not.

Comment: Don't you need double colons after the label when it's inside a `PROC` to make it visible outside the procedure? I.e. `section::`

Comment: I don't know masm too well but I don't think labels are scoped ... you should just do `jmp section`

Comment: You should take care of the _stack frame_ created by the `PROC` directive.  `PROC` creates a `push ebp`, which may be of relevance if you jump across procedures.

Comment: @Michael This was the problem...I just didn't know I needed to do that syntactically.  Solved my issue!

Comment: You can do it but it's bad practice, hard to maintain - when you change that function's stack requirements you'll have to hunt down any other functions that jump into it. Better to restructure the code into smaller units? "rat's nest" comes to mind.

Comment: Because, you know, assembly language programming isn't hard enough already. It wouldn't be a real program if it didn't include a bunch of sloppy spaghetti. If you find yourself needing to do this, *you're probably doing something wrong*! Go back and fix the fundamental problem rather than hacking in a solution that you or somebody else will hate you for later.

Answer (score 4):

According to this link, using a double-colon makes the label non-scoped

http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Assembler/alt.lang.asm/2006-11/msg00909.html

I just made an example and it is working as expected

```
.686P
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK 4096

EXTERN      _printf     :PROC

.DATA
msg     BYTE    "testing", 0dh, 0ah, 0

.CODE

_main   PROC

    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

    call    _other
lbl1::
    add     esp, 4
    push    OFFSET msg
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4

    xor     eax, eax
    pop     ebp
    ret

_main   ENDP

_other  PROC

    jmp     lbl1
    ret

_other  ENDP

END
```

To compile on VS 2015 command prompt:

```
ml jumps.asm /link legacy_stdio_definitions.lib msvcrt.lib
```